# Uno Platform: R.java invalid symbol name

Tags: android, rjava, uno-platform

I'm getting this output in VS 2019 when trying to build the solution for Android platform:

```
(...).R.java : error APT2258: invalid symbol name 'UnoTPA.UnoTPA:drawable/import'.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

No idea why of this error. If I've understood correctly, this file is created automatically with some data about the interface, but when I open this file, it is empty.

If it is helpful, build action on the same solution on UWP works fine. I'm new to Uno platform.

Any idea why is happening this?

Comment: Any Update on this? i am facing same issue

Comment: No. I'm facing the same issues. And no clue why is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: Hello, Issue resolved. it was issue of Image name is same like Predefined Keyword at my end. kindly check at your end as well under Resource folder

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more, please?

Answer (score 0):

For any further guys that have that problem or a similiar. My problem figured out as there was a link in some android files in the background to a file that was already deleted. I've right clicked my project file and run "Create and supress open problems".

I know it's not the cleanest solution but after this, i recreated the whole project again on the "normal" way and all links to the corrupt file we're gone. So i think the project just needed a kickstart to clean the background files from android.

I'm using VS2022 17.4.5 and have a .NET MAUI project.